# Springboot overiding multiple properties files in config

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have 2 properties files other than **application.properties**

Ex:

```
application.properties

abc.properties

def.properties

config/
```

by default spring will override **application.properties** in root with the one in **config/** but not the others (if add another **abc.properties**) inside **config** directory.

What I'm trying to achieve is to override properties by adding the required one in **config/** directory.

**abc.properties** and **def.properties**  are invoked using

```
@PropertySource({"classpath:abc.properties","classpath:def.properties"})
```

**config/** directory may or may not have properties files, if there then it should override.

Comment: You are telling to spring to load them from classpath.  So it makes sense to not look into config folder.

Comment: Is there  any other way to look into config directory for other property files